# roxygen2 importFrom and binary operator

Tags: r, roxygen2

What is the way to format a call to `importFrom` while using `roxygen2`?

I can see two approaches:

```
importFrom base %in%
```

or

```
importFrom base `%in%`
```

Obviously we wouldn't import a base function into a package but this is for demo's sake.

Comment: Take a look at `help("namespace_roclet", "roxygen2")`

Comment: I did Dason is there something there in particular that answers this question?

Comment: Well it is the documentation.  And there is nothing in there to suggest that you would need quotes around the function name.

Answer (score 3):

I tested it out [HERE](https://github.com/trinker/rmini/blob/master/R/binop.R) and it seems:

```
importFrom base %in%
```

is appropriate

Comment: Note that `importFrom` seems to be out of favor: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html