# R could not find function "%dopar%"

Tags: r, parallel-processing

In RStudio in Windows 10 I wrote a function that performs calculations in parallel, like the following:

```
doSomething = function(a, b, c) {

    # Inner function that does the actual work when parallelised
    work = function (a, b, c) {
        # Do something
        e = func1(a, b)
        f = func2(c)
        result = e + f

        return(result)
    }

    # Carry out work in parallel
    cl = makeCluster(6)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    output = foreach(i = 1:10, .packages=c("foo", "bar")) %dopar%
        work(a, b, c)
    stopCluster(cl)

    return(output)
}
```

This works fine and dandy if I load the function into memory from an R script; however, I want to include it in a package that I am writing. As such, in the package file, I am careful to identify the namespace of the external functions and refer to their packages in the `DESCRIPTION` file. For example:

```
doSomething = function(a, b, c) {

    # Inner function that does the actual work when parallelised
    work = function (a, b, c) {
        # Do something
        e = foo::func1(a, b)
        f = bar::func2(c)
        result = e + f

        return(result)
    }

    # Carry out work in parallel
    cl = parallel::makeCluster(6)
    doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
    output = foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .packages=c("foo", "bar")) %dopar%
        work(a, b, c)
    parallel::stopCluster(cl)

    return(output)
}
```

and in the `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
...
Imports:
    foo,
    bar,
    doParallel,
    foreach,
    parallel
```

(Edit) the `NAMESPACE` file contains the following:

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.1): do not edit by hand

export(doSomething)
```

The problem is, when I build my package and run the function out of the package, I get the following error and execution stops:

```
Error in doSomething(a, b, c):
    could not find function "%dopar%"
```

Since `%dopar%` is an operator, not a function, I can't prepend it with `foreach::` in my package function.

I am not sure what I need to do to get it to work properly. Furthermore 95% of similar problems I've read about are caused by an omission from `.packages()` causing the error, not the `%dopar%` operator itself not being recognised. That would not appear to be the cause here.

Please help!

Comment: Do you have a "Depends" line in your DESCRIPTION file which includes the foreach package.

Comment: What's in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: @VenYao No, I don't.

Comment: The Imports lines in your DESCRIPTION file should better be in the NAMESPACE file. And you should include this line in your DESCRIPTION  file: Depends: R (>= 2.14.0), foreach, parallel, doParallel

Comment: I think you want `importFrom(foreach,"%dopar%")` in your NAMESPACE file

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280696/roxygen2-importfrom-and-binary-operator since it appears your are using roxygen which should update the NAMESPACE file for you

Comment: How about open the source file of a package which imports `foreach` and see how `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION` are written?

Comment: It's probably not the correct answer but your belief that an R operator always needs to be used in its infix syntax deserves re-examination. You should always be able to use it as `foreach::`%dopar%`( arg1, arg2)`. That's what the parser converts it to.

Comment: @MrFlick adding `importFrom(foreach,"%dopar%")` seems to do the trick. I'm not sure why, though, if `foreach` is already in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: @BondedDust Can you describe how to reformat the corresponding line in my example in order to achieve that? What are `arg1` and `arg1`?

Comment: arg1 and arg2 would be: `.packages=c("foo", "bar"))` and `work(a, b, c)`

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for problem with foreach %dopar% is to reinstall these packages:

```
install.packages("doSNOW")

install.packages("doParallel") 

install.packages("doMPI")
```

Above packages are responsible for parallelism in R. Bug which existed in old versions of these packages is now removed. I should mention that it will most likely help even though you are not using these packages in your project/package directly.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar situation, and I was having difficulty doing something like `foreach::%dopar%`. So, using [Mr. Flick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) comments I just updated my function documentation to include a line like `@importFrom foreach %dopar%` In other words, your function can look like this so you cna use %dopar% without `::` operator:

```
#' Do a thing
#'
#' @param first
#' @param second
#' @returns stuff
#' @export
#' @importFrom foreach %dopar%
foo <- function(first, second){

  # I can just use %dopar% without :: operator
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1)
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  # foreach::`%dopar%`(
  foreach::foreach(i = 1:nrow(everyCombo), .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
    .
    .
    .
  }
  parallel::stopCluster(cl)

}
```

Then call `devtools::document()`, and it will take care of the rest.